# How to compare 2 dataframes in PySpark based on 2 columns?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark I'm trying to compare 2 dataframes which a common columns. Tha dataframes looks like this:

```
df1   ...   ...
aa1   ...   ...
bb2   ...   ...
ab3   ...   ...
cc4   ...   ...

df2   ...   ...
a1    ...   ...
b3    ...   ...
```

The idea is to check if df1 contains rows with the substring of df2. If so, get those rows. The result from above would be then:

```
result
aa1
ab3
```

Or in pseudocode:

```
df1.filter(df1.col.likes(df2.col))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to use `join` with conditions

Comment: what is the rule ? why do you have ab3 in your result ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Basically, you check if the first dataframe contains the value from the 2nd dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a `leftsemi` join.

Syntax will be `df1.join(df2, how='leftsemi', on="join condition")`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1.show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|aa1|
|bb2|
|ab3|
|cc4|
+---+

df2.show()
+---+
|  b|
+---+
| a1|
| b3|
+---+

df1.join(F.broadcast(df2), how='leftsemi', on=F.col('a').endswith(F.col('b'))).show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|aa1|
|ab3|
+---+
```

Comment: Is there a way to append the columns from the 2nd df with the first one? Then this solution would be more than perfect!

Comment: @Kishintai replace `leftsemi` with `inner`

Comment: I have a follow-up question, dropping the link, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823544/pyspark-mapping-multiple-columns @Steven